# git rebase to merge two commits on same branch

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I have 2 commits on master branch.
Lets say
Commit A
Commit B
Commit C
All the above changes are already pushed to remote.

I rebased and merged commits A and B to create commit AB. So master branch log says
Commit AB
Commit C

git push give me error "changes rejected". I have an option of using git push --force.
But I am skeptical in using that. If I push above "Commit AB" changes to remote, will it cause any problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will cause problems if others have pulled from the remote.  If nobody has pulled, then you can use `--force` without worry.